# TSQL - Do the JOIN predicates order matter

Tags: performance, t-sql, join

I know there is a lot of discussion on WHERE predicates order mattering/not mattering and where to put the predicates WHERE clause vs ON clause, but what about JOIN predicate order?

For example, is there any performance difference between:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 AS a
JOIN table2 AS b ON
    a.key1 = b.key1
    AND a.key2 = b.key2
```

versus

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 AS a
JOIN table2 AS b ON
    a.key2 = b.key2
    AND a.key1 = b.key1
```

Is there a performance difference? Could there be? If so, in what edge cases?

Thanks

Comment: No, they (*should*) both generate the same query plan.  You can easily confirm this by looking at the generated query plans for both queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query optimizer will select the query plan.  They are the same query.